# change column attribute in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

After using `tbl_df` in `dplyr` I got an object where some columns have attribute of `<dbl>`. I wonder if there is any easy way to change these columns to `<chr>` using `dplyr`? Thanks.

Comment: The Hadleyverse hasn't renamed every base R function yet. Using `as.character(x)` should do the job quite well ;-)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Thanks, but it does not seem to work... Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  as.character(x)

Comment: In that case it would be nice to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) in your question. That makes it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: You're mutating, not selecting: `mutate(some_column = as.character(some_column)` or `mutate_each(funs(as.character))`

Comment: @alistaire Thank you! This is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mutate(some_column = as.character(some_column)` or `mutate_each(funs(as.character))` will do the work. Thanks @alistaire.